# LAN-to-WAN puzzle

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan

I have as primary router an ASUS RT-AC51U (A) (where only 3-4 clients are connected via wifi with address reservation and / or static IP on the machine), as secondary one ASUS RT-AC1200G + (B) (here they are connected 10 clients via wifi and LAN port, including a NAS, Raspberry, etc. Also here there are clients with address reservation and other static IPs). It works perfectly but I have a problem: if I'm connected to router B, I can also access router A, on the contrary when I'm connected to router A, I can not connect either to router B or to NAS etc, obviously because I find on different LAN network classes right?

Router Configuration A
Static IP WAN (assigned by ISP) = 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask WAN = 255.255.255.0
Gateway (assigned by ISP)
Public IP = (static)
IP LAN = 192.168.2.1
Subnet Mask LAN = 255.255.255.0
DHCP LAN = from 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.254
DNS = From ISP
IP LAN Router B (Assigned by me) = 192.168.2.2

Router Configuration B
IP WAN (automatic) = 192.168.2.2
Subnet Mask WAN (automatic) = 255.255.255.0
Gateway (automatic) = 192.168.2.1
DNS (automatic) = 192.168.2.1
IP LAN = 192.168.3.1
Subnet Mask LAN = 255.255.255.0
DHCP LAN = from 192.168.3.2 to 192.168.3.254

I state that I have a house on three floors and the primary router A is on the last floor above, the router B at the bottom below. Before I had chosen the LAN-to-LAN configuration but, being the router less efficient and without Gigabit ports than the router B, I wanted to try to manage most of the clients and streaming traffic etc, to the router B.
But now I have the problems explained at the beginning, does anyone have a solution?

Thanks everyone in advance guys

Comment: Check out whether router B can be configured as an access point rather than a router. Currently router B puts a firewall and NAT between the two networks.

Comment: Yes, the router B can be configured in Acces Point Mode, but I think I will return to the solution I have already tried, ie in LAN-to-LAN, simply extending the network from the top to the bottom and unfortunately managing everything to primary router A, which is less performing.

Comment: I read a few days ago the answers given here https://superuser.com/questions/641036/can-i-chain-two-routers-together-keeping-dhcp-on-both, I still have not tried though and I do not know if it's more or less like my problem.